# How do i address this issue. Try to run the code but pops up with this errors

Tags: flutter

[child: FlatButton(
child: Text(
'CHECKOUT',
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
fontSize: 22.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
letterSpacing: 2.0,
),](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z4Ps.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

the `FlatButton` is deprecated from flutter
use `TextButton` instead.

```
    TextButton(
     onPressed: () {},
     child: Text("button"),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

the `FlatButton` widget is deprecated try using `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` instead of it.

just replace the widget `FlatButton`.